# Insert an \n instead of wrapping text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Is it possible to insert a newline (`\n`) whenever a `textarea` wraps in **JavaScript**? So basically, if there is an overflow, a newline separator should be inserted automatically.

And how would you do it? I need to insert explicit `\n` symbols. Just wrapping the text won't work.

Comment: of course you meant \n not /n. I am not sure what you mean, because i think the default behaviour is that your text is wrapped to the new line..

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not submitting to a server then you need to splice the newlines in manually. Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kug8N/) using jQuery. You could probably reduce the example down to straight JS easily enough if you don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifiy a `wrap="hard"` attribute on your textarea then a newline character will be sent in your form data wherever a visual break occurs in the textarea.  The resulting tag would be:

```
<textarea name="mytext" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

Comment: Does it work in both Chrome and Firefox? Just tried it in Firefox. Didn't work.

Comment: Works in FF5 and Chrome 13 for me.

Comment: +1 @Nick, yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PTH/ The test doesn't work. The newlines are not yet added when you get the value. But the submitted data does contain the breaks. If you hold Ctrl+Shift while you click the submit button, you get a new tab where you can see %0A%0D in the url. Those are the breaks. Tested in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: It's not in a form. I can't submit it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9PTH/1/ Works in FF too. (Added a target to the form for the demo. Ctrl+Shift apparently won't work).

Comment: FYI, I tested on Ye Olde FF 3.6.

Comment: **@GolezTrol** *In my case*, it is not in a form.

Comment: I think I see what you're going for now. I just submitted a new answer that splices newlines into the textarea using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!
I've created an iframe with a jsp inside and an identical textarea and before to send the textarea to the server by ajax, I made a submit to the jsp page, so then my data are correctly formatted. It works fine.

Comment: You should be more specific about answering the question