# How to detect the auto line breaking in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the textarea content as it is; i.e, How can i get text content with auto line breaking? I have to place the text as it is on the canvas.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately one issue with < canvas > tag is the lack of text-metrics support which ends to not supporting line breaking!

To simulate word-wrapping you need to loop through the singular words in your text (text.split(“ “)), and measuring each word individually until the edge of the bounding-box is hit, at which point a break is inserted, and the process continues.

For more detail information and also implementation guide, please take a look at this article:

- http://mudcu.be/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/

I hope this helps :-)