# Detect line breaks in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea, new-operator, lines

Anyone knows a technique or method to find the position of the natural text line breaks in a textarea using javascript? It's not about finding \n or `<br/>`'s.

Comment: Possibly similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text

Comment: That's gonna be very hard to do, if possible at all. You could find them easily in a div though.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks for the heads up, I will check that out. By natural I meant where it wraps in a textarea naturally, not by user entered line break.

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this directly, but the answer to this question uses a trick to find them where it adds characters one by one and checks for scrolling:
[finding "line-breaks" in textarea that is word-wrapping ARABIC text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text)