# How can I determine the positions of "new lines" in the text of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, word-wrap

Adding long text inside an HTML element such as a DIV, the element wraps that text. Exactly like this Question text, actually. 
How can I take the text from such an HTML element and determine where it breaks? i.e. where a new line is inserted.

For instance, in this box, there's a new line after "...like this", one after "...where it" and two after "...is inserted."

Comment: [This might be of some help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: Unless the element is constrained by assigned width and height (or rows and cols in a testarea) , the newlines wrap according to the available width, and can change if the window is resized. Also, a user with a different screen size, or preferences for a different text size (even with the same viewport as you), will not see the same line break positions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671713/detecting-line-breaks-with-jquery

Comment: @katspaugh I need to be able to take that text and split it in multiple strings. Each string will hold the message on a single line. And it should not matter if the CSS 'word-wrap' rule is set to 'break-word', I still need to detect each single line of text. This is all for converting some standard HTML elements which hold text and/or a photo into an HTML5 canvas. And unfortunately, the '.fillText()' method is not smart enough to break a piece of text for me, so I need to "manually" detect each line.

Comment: @kennebec Obviously, but this is not an issue. Whatever the size of the element and the screen resolution, I simply need to break such a wrapped text into sub-strings, each sub-string constituting a line of text from the original element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is actually **how to do word-wrapping in HTML5 canvas**:

> This is all for converting some standard HTML elements which hold text
>   and/or a photo into an HTML5 canvas. And unfortunately, the
>   '.fillText()' method is not smart enough to break a piece of text for
>   me, so I need to "manually" detect each line.

What you might do is [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#measureText%28%29) subsequently adding one word at a time. Measure the first word, and if it fits to the width of your container (`ctx2d.measureText(words).width <= containerWidth`), then you can add another word and measure again. Until the string of words doesn't fit. If it doesn't – you have to `fillText` on the next line.

As for the manually inserted line breaks, they are specifically represented in HTML, either by `\n` or `\r` characters in textareas or by HTML elements, like `<br \>`. Thus, before measuring the text you might want to split it by paragraphs.

In textareas:

```
var paragraphs = textarea.value.split('\n');
```

In non-form elements:

```
var paragraphs = [];

// getting all <p> and elements in a typical HTML element
// as well as individual text nodes (they are just DOM-nodes),
// separated by <br /> elements
var innerNodes = nonFormElement.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, len = innerNodes.length; i += 1) {
    // if a sub-element has some text in it,
    // add the text to our list
    var content = innerNodes[i].textContent;
    if (content) {
        paragraphs.push(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the closest solution to what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, to take the full text and start adding a character at a time to a 'buffer' string and after each insertion, measure the length (in pixels) of that buffer. However, this doesn't solve the problem of actual line breaks. That is, I might be able to leave a few blank lines. How would I then detect these lines?

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't understand the approach on non-form elements. Nevertheless, I'm using a textarea to append the content to it, then use the .split() method to detect the newline characters, and in conjunction with the measureText() method, I believe I'll be able to reach my goal. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreiOniga, I've annotated the non-form approach to clarify. Good look!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. But here's a simple trick you can use to identify the positions of single words. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NW5jj/)

---

```
var $text = $('#text'),
    breaks = [],
    top;

// wrap words (\w+) and punctuation (\S+) [well, non-word and non-space]
// in <spans> we can easily identify
$text.html($text.text().replace(/(\w+|\S+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));

$text.children().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        _top = $this.position().top;

    if (top === undefined) {
        top = _top;
    } else if (top < _top) {
        top = _top;
        // moved a row down
        breaks.push($this.prev());
        $this.prev().css('color', 'red');
    }
});


console.log(breaks);
```

Comment: Rod, I appreciate your help on this. However, as I've commented on katspaugh's answer, I don't see how this can solve the issue of line breaks. Because I may (or may not) press 'Return' a few times and insert 1 or more blank lines. And I'd not be able to detect those lines and draw them as they are, on the canvas. Any ideas on how to 'fix' this problem?