# use window.getSelection get selected or cursor located text line from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getselection

I am dynamically filling textarea using Ajax call's. In my code, I want to get the  cursor's  current line content using window.getSelection.  I tried following code,

`var range = window.getSelection().toString;

                                  alert (typeof(range));`

But, It returns function as alert Message. or Any other better way, to get the cursor's current  line content from textarea that code need to support in all browser's.? Once I get the current line content I will find out line number and update new content on it.

Comment: Just to address the question about the `typeof` result, `toString` is indeed a function.  You probably intended to invoke it: `window.getSelection().toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, textareas have a different selection API from regular content: use [`selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) of the textarea rather than `window.getSelection()`.

Secondly, getting the current line requires some creative coding if you're accounting for the browser's auotmatic wrapping of content. I've seen a few questions about this in Stack Overflow. Here's one example:

[finding "line-breaks" in textarea that is word-wrapping ARABIC text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text)