# How to get string representation of an HTML5 textarea converting wraps into line breakings?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have a textarea HTML5 input with `cols=120` set. When a user types a long string on it, the string may get wrapped into several lines, to fit the specified columns.

However, when I try to retrieve the text value of the element, the long string is not with any kind of line breaks associated.

Is there a way to get a string representation from the textarea which includes linebreaks exactly where the long string got wrapped, so that it goes the exact same way it was displayed into the screen?

Comment: Line breaks occures only when user hits Enter, end of line does not create new line symbol

Comment: So, you mean there´s no way, right?

Comment: There are no linebreaks.  What you perceive as linebreaks are just where the text wraps.  It's actually just one long string.

Comment: Yes. I know. That´s exact what I meant, I´ll update the question. How to get a representation of that long string in way to convert these wraps into line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<textarea wrap="hard" ...` to submit a form including line breaks as it appears to the user.

Comment: I´ve tried this before asking, but didn´t work for my scenario. I´ve updated the question also.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueMartinsLinsRol Are you trying to the get the text in a script? If so, I'd suggest you add a tag `javascript` to your question. An example of what you're expecting and what you're getting would also help.

Comment: I see your point @GOTO0.  I´m trying to fetch the value on a angularjs script indeed, and pass it to a XHR request later on.
Would it work if it wasn´t an Ajax call, but a plain form-submit?

Answer (score 0):

Use .val() to get value of textarea and use $.trim() to empty spaces.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var val = $.trim($("textarea").val());
if (val != "") {1
    $('div').append('<pre>'+val+'</pre>');
}
});
```

**Demo** : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVUsZ/54/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems promising.Will test it here.

[finding "line-breaks" in textarea that is word-wrapping ARABIC text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text?rq=1)

Thanks SO Related answers!