# Textarea split text by physical line instead of newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

It's trivial splitting a `textarea` by newline using `split('\n')`.

Can you split a proportional-font `textarea` so that each *wrapped* line is a separate element in the array?

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, I was afraid of that.  HTML5 adds the `wrap="hard"` attribute, but it's unfortunate that the browser doesn't expose the breaks until after form submission.  There are interesting techniques for detecting soft wraps at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text

Comment: That's a nice hack, does it work?

Comment: I haven't tried that particular technique, but I came up with a similar one last night using a `div` to hold the `textarea` contents.  It works fairly well in Chrome if I set identical properties on both elements for `font`, `letter-spacing`, `padding`, `width`, and `word-spacing`; and if I set the `div`'s `word-wrap:break-word`.  I also replace `\n`s with `<br>`s, and all double-spaces with space+&nbsp;.  However, I can't seem to come up with a style that will make IE wrap a `div` like it does a `textarea`.

Comment: Another question I have, which may be impossible, is can we get the text within `getClientRects()`?  This would greatly simplify the split, if only I could duplicate a `textarea`'s style in a `div`.

Comment: I really don't know, i'm sorry. On the `div`, I would be able to to get the line break, but but it would require to loop over all character, which is not optimal.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm not hopeful for a `getClientRects()` -> text solution, so I'll experiment with the technique I linked to.  Thanks!