# How do I detect whether a position is at the beginning of a line in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a textarea like this:

```
<textarea>
this is test1
and this is test2
plus it is test3
</textarea>
```

As you see, this positions are in the beginning of line: `0` (t), `14` (a), `32` (p).

---

Now I need to determine whether a position (I mean is the number of position) is at the beginning of a line?

For example:

```
10 : false
5  : false
14 : true
40 : false
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @Gavriel I just can get the position of specific character ... But now I don't know how can I determine that position is in the beginning of line or not ..

Comment: Do you have line breaks in your text ? I don't think you can directly detect word wrapping, but you may want to read Shadow Wizard's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know that the n-th position is at the beginning, then:

```
n == 0 || $("#textbox").val()[n-1] == '\n'
```

Comment: Works perfectly ... +1

Comment: Do I need to replace `\n` with `\n|\r|\r\n` ?

Comment: no because this is a string comparsion, not a RegEx, but you might need to modify the check in a way to make sure it works on win,mac as well. I think it is enough to test for \n or \n in [n-1], because that would also work when [n-2]=='\r', [n-1]=='\n'

Answer (score 3):

The contents of a `textarea` are stored in its `value` property. Here, new lines are represented by the ASCII new line non-printing character `\n`. We can split apart the the value of the `textarea` to give us an array which contains each line.

Next, we make another array, which will contain the starting positions of each line. We add 0 as an implied value. Next, we loop through the entire `text` array (starting from the second line as we have already added the first), and each time add an element to the `lines` array which is the `lines` array value for the `text` item before this one and the length of the `text` item before this one.

The logic in this is that:

- The `lines` array contains all of the previous starting positions
- The length of the previous `text` item added to the previous `lines` item results in (in your examples) something such as `0 + "this is test1".length` = 13, which of course is one off.
- So, we add one, yielding `0 + "this is test1".length + 1` = 14, and `14 + "and this is test2".length + 1` = 32.

Then, we simply test that `pos` (the position that we want to check; passed to the function) is in the `lines` array. If it is, then the result is `true`, else it's `false`.

Javascript Code:

```
function testpos(pos) {
    var text = document.getElementById("textareaid").value.split("\n");
    var lines = [0];
    for (i=1;i<text.length;i++) {
        lines.push(lines[i-1]+text[i-1].length+1)
    }
    return lines.indexOf(parseInt(pos))!=-1
}
```

You'll need this as your HTML:

```
<textarea id="textareaid">this is test1
and this is test2
plus it is test3</textarea>
```

And, here's a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g562gtge/

Comment: Sorry, I messed up that last line of Javascript when I posted - all fixed now, and added an explanation + live demo :D

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jyg61t1b/)

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('ta1'),
  taText = ta.textContent;

var lines = taText.trim().split('\n');

for (var i in lines) {
  console.log(lines[i][0]);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta1">
this is test1
and this is test2
plus it is test3
</textarea>
```

Comment: Do I need to replace `\n` with `\n|\r|\r\n` ?

Comment: If you try it yourself, you'll get [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/jyg61t1b/1/), as you can see it will only outputs the first "**`t`**" and that because **`\n`** "newline" differs slightly than **`\r`** or **`\r\n`**, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them